# Remove scopes from Firebase OAuthProvider('google.com')

Tags: oauth, firebase-authentication, openid-connect

I am using a vanilla configuration of the firebase Auth SDK. It is currently asking for all of these scopes.

[image]

I do not need profile picture or name, and would love to remove them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is No name, and picture permissions are granted to your application when you request the profile scope as part of signin.

## explanation

Assuming you are following the example found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.OAuthProvider).  If you check the lines called addScopes.

```
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
```

This is where you define what permissions your applicating needs.  The email and profile scopes are part of [Google sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#google-sign-in) (Open Id Connect)  The profile scope give you access to some basic profile information about the user.  Part of basic profile information is their picture.

[image]

These two claims are actually returned by the user info endpoint. This is the response from the userinfo endpoint when I authorized only with the profile scope.

```
{
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhroCYJp2P9xeYeYk1npchBPK-zbtTxzNQo0WAHI20=s96-c", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "1172004755376"
}
```

This is all default, so its not something you can change.

## full example

```
// Using a redirect.
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
  if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you the OAuth Access Token for that provider.
    var token = result.credential.accessToken;
  }
  var user = result.user;
});

// Start a sign in process for an unauthenticated user.
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('google.com');
provider.addScope('profile');
provider.addScope('email');
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
```